# Android: How to find scale ratio of background image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, aspect-ratio

OK, so I have an image that I am using in an ImageView to fill the screen. I am keeping the aspect ratio by using scaletype="centerCrop", as seen here:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/full_bg" />
```

In code, how do I go about finding the scale ratio, or scale factor, that resulted from the original image to the scaled image? I need to know so I can apply this same ratio to a button positioned strategically on top of the background. This is what I have tried to get the scale ratio:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Log.i("Test", "x scale = " + Float.toString(view.getScaleX()));
```

This returns a 1.0 (unscaled) which isn't what I'm looking for. I also tried getting the dimensions of the scaled Bitmap instead of the ImageView, which also gives me the original image size (540px):

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Drawable drawing = view.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();
Log.i("Test", "width = " + Integer.toString(bitmap.getWidth()));
```

Am I approaching this all wrong? I can't find anything to help me figure this out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Mark, are you getting the scale and bitmap width in onCreate or somewhere else?  I ask because in onCreate the components are actually not yet drawn to the screen.  So asking for getWidth may be returning the default size before scaling occurs.  Try overriding onWindowFocusChanged and see what the values are there (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean))

Comment: Why are you not taking height and width of image view ?

Comment: @spartygw I was getting scale and bitmap width in onCreate, so I tried overriding onWindowFocusChanged as you suggested, but still got the same results.

Comment: @Tarun Varshney - Because the dimensions of the image view are just the dimensions of the device being used. By using scaleType="centerCrop" both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view. These are the dimensions I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I got this to change the image size depending on the size of the screen, but this could be easily changed by changing

```
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

to be

```
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
```

or whatever you want it to be scaled to.  Note width is the size you're going to.

```
    public static void changeImageSize(ImageView object, Context context){

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        BitmapDrawable bmap = (BitmapDrawable) object.getDrawable();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) object.getLayoutParams();   
        float bmapWidth = bmap.getBitmap().getWidth();
        float bmapHeight = bmap.getBitmap().getHeight();

        int newBmapWidth = (int) (bmapWidth*width/480);
        int newBmapHeight = (int) (bmapHeight*height/800);
        layout.width = newBmapWidth;
        layout.height = newBmapHeight;
        object.setLayoutParams(layout);
    }
```

Comment: I'll have to look into this to see if it addresses what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for the suggestion.